# How to Append two json files on same html page through different links in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, append

**I am trying to load and append 2 results through 2 different json files**.
My Html File is as Follow

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard" class="has-subheader">
  <ion-content scroll="false">
    <div class="row" style="padding-left:55px;">
        <div class="col col-60" style="border-radius: 20px; height:90%;border: 2px solid #73AD21;min-height:240px;">
            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="input in inputs" id="content">
                <div ng-switch="input.type">
                    <div  ng-switch-when="text" > 
                        <label class="">{{input.name}}</label>
                        <input  type="text" value="{{input.value}}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="checkbox">
                        <input  type="checkbox" value="outputs[input.name]"/ >                              
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="button" class="btn-group inline pull-left">
                        <input ID="{{input.id}}" type="submit" value="{{input.value}}" class="{{input.class}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col col-40" style="border-radius: 20px; height:90%;border: 2px solid #73AD21;">
            <a ng-click="loadPeople($event)" class="pointer" id="1">Link 1</a><br> 
            <a ng-click="loadPeople($event)" class="pointer" id="2">Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The cotroller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('ChatsCtrl',function($scope,$http){
   $scope.loadPeople = function(event) {
             $scope.outputs = {};
             $scope.inputs = {};

             if(event.target.id==1)
             {
                var object1=  $http.get('js/link1.json').success(function(response){
                $scope.inputs=response;
                });
             }
             else if(event.target.id==2){
                var object2=$http.get('js/link2.json').success(function(response){
                $scope.inputs=response;
                });
            }
        };

})
```

The link1.json

```
[{
 "type": "text",
 "value":"First",
 "name": "first",
 "required":"true"
}, {
"type":"button",
"value":"First",
"id":"first",
"class":"btn-primary"
},{
"type":"button",
"value":"Second",
"id":"second",
"class":"btn-danger"
},{
"type":"button",
"value":"Third",
"id":"Third",
"class":"btn-assertive"
}]
```

The link2.json

```
[{
 "type": "text",
 "name": "first"
},
{
 "type": "text",
 "name": "fifth"
}, {
 "type": "checkbox",
 "name": "third"
},{
 "type": "text",
 "name": "second"
} ]
```

Current results
[When I click on link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK01F.png)

[When I click on link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRZtj.png)

I want to append and display data coming from link2.json when I click on it. Plz help me or provide useful links, I am new to angularjs. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: `$scope.inputs = $scope.inputs.concat(response);`. You should probably declare inputs as an array also: `$scope.inputs = [];`.

Comment: will apply and let u know soon

Comment: I changed it as per but not wrked    $scope.inputs = [];
    
    if(event.target.id==1)
    {
    var object1=  $http.get('js/link1.json').success(function(response){
     
     
$scope.inputs = $scope.inputs.concat(response);
    });
    }
    else{
    var object1=$http.get('js/text.json').success(function(response){
   
     
$scope.inputs = $scope.inputs.concat(response);
    });
   }
    };

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry didn't see your data object is in fact an array - not an object. Extend would extend the properties, appending data from one array to the other is default javascript and, like the comments suggest, done by calling `.concat`. Since that doesn't seem to work, try putting your code (or a working snippet) in a plunker, so we can see where the real problem lies.

I still (without a plunker) see your problem solved like this:

```
$scope.inputs = []; // This is important to set before you try and call concat on it.
```

And then in both your callbacks:

```
// Make sure you only concat the data and not the whole response.
$scope.inputs.concat(response.data);
```

Perhaps it's because you try and concat the response and not the data from the response? Check this link out for more information:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @omkar If this solved your initial question, you should flag an answer as correct and create a new question for your drag feature, describing it in further details. It will also attract a new set of eyes to look at your problem.  It's generally a bad idea to extend the initial question to a broader scope.

Comment: I  improved it as per your suggestion,and i can not able to see proper flag setting due to low rating .

Comment: @omkar I don't understand? You had another question (not about joining the two results) - that should be posted in a new Stack Overflow question.